# Z3: disable lambda functions for array models

Tags: z3

I am currently working with arrays and in some cases Z3 returns lambda functions for them in the produced model.

An example of my code:

```
(set-option :random-seed 0)
(set-option :produce-models true)
(set-option :produce-unsat-cores true)
; 
(set-info :status sat)
(declare-fun tmp_bv3 () (_ BitVec 4))
(declare-fun tmp_array2 () (Array (_ BitVec 4) Bool))
(declare-fun tmp_bool3 () Bool)
(declare-fun tmp_bool0 () Bool)
(assert
 (let ((?x564 (store tmp_array2 tmp_bv3 tmp_bool3)))
 (let (($x33 (bvult tmp_bv3 tmp_bv3)))
 (let ((?x237 (bvurem tmp_bv3 tmp_bv3)))
 (let ((?x24 (store tmp_array2 tmp_bv3 tmp_bool0)))
 (= (store ?x24 ?x237 $x33) ?x564))))))
(check-sat)

(get-value (tmp_array2 tmp_bv3 tmp_bool0 tmp_bool3 ))
(get-info :reason-unknown)
```

For this example Z3 version 4.8.6 returned the following model:

```
((tmp_array2 ((as const (Array (_ BitVec 4) Bool)) false))
 (tmp_bv3 #x0)
 (tmp_bool0 false)
 (tmp_bool3 false))
```

And the current version (4.8.12) returns:

```
((tmp_array2 (lambda ((x!1 (_ BitVec 4))) (= x!1 #x0)))
 (tmp_bv3 #x0)
 (tmp_bool0 false)
 (tmp_bool3 false))
```

For my use case of the results returned by Z3, I would prefer the format returned by version 4.8.6.
And therefore I was wondering if an option exists to disable lambda functions in the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

z3's model printing around arrays have been in flux recently; and different versions do print the models in different ways. (For instance, see https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/5604)

If I try your program using the latest z3 from GitHub master, then it prints:

```
sat
((tmp_array2 ((as const (Array (_ BitVec 4) Bool)) false))
 (tmp_bv3 #x1)
 (tmp_bool0 false)
 (tmp_bool3 false))
(:reason-unknown "")
```

So, it appears this behavior is indeed currently restored in the repo. But you are correct that you might get a lambda-output depending on which version you're using.

So far as I know there's no explicit option you can use to control this behavior. If you can compile from the master (https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) that'll solve your problem. If not, I'm afraid you're out of luck. You could of course report this as an issue in their tracker, but since the latest master does the right thing, I guess the answer you'll get will be "upgrade."